# How smooth is parquetry?

Tags: hardwood-floor

Can you feel the texture of the wood in a parquetry floor?

I'm writing a novel and describing someone feeling the floor, but don't know if in a parquetry floor you would be able to feel the wood's texture.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to research this by visiting a local flooring store and feeling them for yourself.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in most cases you can feel the texture of the pattern with feet and fingers. Parquet floors tend to present slight differences in height among the individual wood components, and slight gaps between them, varying in width on a seasonal basis. Depending on the age and type, they can be rather creaky, since some are floating (not adhered to a substrate). The grain of the wood (usually oak) is also apparent in many cases.

It's more rare that the wood is bonded so well to a substrate that no variation in height occurs. This would generally indicate a simulated parquet floor.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the quality of the parquetry, and the quality of the installation.

Hardwood floors often have rounded edges on the boards so that slight irregularities in the subfloor don't result in a 'micro cliff' between adjacent boards.  The locking system between planks helps with this.  The result is a bunch of 1/32" deep grooves that excel at collecting dirt.  This comes and goes with fashion but the milled edge can be used to disguise poor quality control.

Parquetry generally is cemented down.  If done well on a smooth subfloor, it will be as smooth as a basketball court.  Done by an amateur, on a lumpy or non perfectly flat floor, it will have gaps and ripples, glue squeeze out.

Parquetry, like hardwood, can be bought pre-finished or ready for final finish sanding then varnishing. The latter can mask some of the earlier mentioned defects.  The quality of the sanding, the use of filler on woods such as oak, the type of varnish, the number of coats, the use of a final wax coating all will affect the appearance and texture.

Could I identify a parquetry floor by touch in the dark?  Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

I have a parquet floor in my living room & kitchen.
The only parts which I would be able to identify by touch are in the kitchen where they've suffered some (as yet unrepaired) water damage.
The rest is all still smooth and flat, so based on my experience no you would not be able to feel the texture in the wood in a parquet floor.